# 'gcloud app deploy app.yaml' not deploying most recent version from Cloud Source Repositories

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, repository, google-app-engine

So I am very new to using GCP. As of right now, I'm using it strictly for my personal website.

My website source is currently on Github and I've connected the repository with Cloud Source Repositories.

From what I've found online, simply re-deploying should incorporate the newly committed changes, but this isn't happening. What am I missing?

---

As a follow-up question, I would like to start using Jenkins to accomplish push-to-deploy **while incurring the least amount of charge possible on my GCP account.**

What would be the most lightweight CI/CD setup with GCP and Jenkins? I'm fairly certain I need Kubernetes as well (which I've never used).

Bottom line, I'm looking for a push-to-deploy setup that is as open-source as possible. The less Google APIs I'm using, the better.

I've done a fair amount of research, but given how new I am to containerization and CI/CD, I am a little clueless as to where I should begin reading.

ANY setup and/or reading material suggestions would be **highly appreciated!**

Thanks,
Mack

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/)

You can look at a quickstart guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker)

And on this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/ci-cd/) you can find 3 specific examples of use cases

For [GCP Jenkins](https://cloud.google.com/jenkins/) you use Kubernetes which is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes) - [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-kubernetes-engine-tutorial)

You mentioned you connected your repo with Cloud Source, you can check the steps for that [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository) to make sure you followed all the steps, After you set up mirroring, Cloud Source Repositories should automatically sync your repository with the mirrored repository when a user commits a change.

You can also consider setting Cloud Build to automatically build your code each time you [push a new commit to GitHub](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/run-builds-on-github)